# ReactJS component hiding for React developer tools

Tags: reactjs

I know the some of the websites using reactJS for the front-end part but they're using some advance technique to hide the component structuring. So we not able to view the component part using the **react developer tool**.

example site - [facebook site](https://www.facebook.com/login/)

Can you please let me know what facebook uses to hide the component structuring?

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code in production

```
<script>
    if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'object') {
        __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.inject = function() {};
    }
</script>
```

Refer react-devtools issue here [#191](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/191)

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I want to hone my view in the Component tree I will go to the **View Settings Menu**, which is the gear icon located by the search component tree bar in the top left:

[image: View Settings Menu Link]

In the View Settings Menu, you can access Component Tree options.  One extremely useful feature is the **Hide Components Where...** filter.  You can enter a regex expression if you wish to exclude a lot of noise from the component tree.  In the example below, I have entered a regex that hides everything except my component named "ContractForm":

[image: View Settings Menu]

That yields the following result in the components pane:

[image: Example]